# Wrapper.exe vs ServerSocket

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, network-programming

Initially i have Occupied port 80 in WildCard address 0.0.0.0
Now i am trying to bind this port 80 in one of the available ipaddress say 172.18.81.56

```
The following exception occurred  
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind  
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)  
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)  
            at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)  
            at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

but while executing the same piece of code from windows service (wrapper.exe) there is no exception, server socket created successfully, what may be the problem...

```
here the piece of code  

    ServerSocket ss = null;  
    try  
    {  
        serverHost = "172.18.81.56";  
        InetAddress ina = InetAddress.getByName(serverHost);  
        ss = new ServerSocket(port, 10, ina);  
        ss.close();  
    }  
    catch(Exception e)  
    {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to 172.18.81.56:80 unless (a) no-one else has bound to 172.18.81.56:80 and (b) no-one else has bound to 0.0.0.0:80.

Comment: I can able to bind 172.18.81.56:80 when the above mentioned code executed from windows service, even another application bound with 0.0.0.0:80, but could not bind the same when executing the same code form cmd prompt in windows.